# Ruby routes and link_to, custom :action route problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get this link:

```
<%= link_to('Edit', :action => 'manage', :id => user) %>
```

even tried explicitly <%= link_to('Edit', {:controller => 'users', :action => 'manage', :id => user}, :method => :get) %>

to show the link in HTML as

```
 '/users/manage/1' or '/users/1/manage'
```

but it shows up as

```
'/users/manage?id=1'
```

I can see in my routes:

```
manage_users GET    /users/manage(.:format)            {:action=>"manage", :controller=>"users"}
...
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
```

so I added a **map.connect**, but it was added to **users**

```
users    GET    /users/manage/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"manage", :controller=>"users"}
```

but without any success.  The link is still '/users/manage?id=1'

This doesn't work anymore than the above.

```
GET    /users/:id/manage(.:format)        {:action=>"manage", :controller=>"users"}
```

Now, when I put the :action in link_to, to 'edit' i.e.

```
<%= link_to('Edit', :action => 'edit', :id => user) %>
```

The **routes.rb edit_user GET /users/:id/edit/(.:format)** works, with a link showing up of

```
'/users/1/edit'
```

How do I get my link_to to show the same link when it is 'manage' instead of 'edit', i.e. showing a link of **'users/1/manage'** instead of **'/users/manage?id=1'**???  Is it because my above **map.connect** is being added to **users**, when it should be added to **'manage_users'**?

Thank for the help.  I'll be trying to figure it out.

Peace.

BTW, **/users/manage?id=1** works, I just want the proper rewrite link to click on.

*EDIT* **routes.rb**

```
map.resources :users, :collection => {:manage => :get}

#map.manage_user '/users/:id/manage', :controller => :users, :action => :manage
#map.resources :users, :member => { :manage  => :get } 
#map.connect 'users/manage/:id(.:format)', :controller => 'users', :action => 'manage',  :conditions => { :method => :get }

map.resources :categories
map.resources :posts
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*so I added a map.connect, but it was added to users*
I suspect you added `map.connect` *after* other definitions, which would give it lowest priority. Try putting it in the beginning of routes.rb file.

You can also use named routes to avoid confusion:

```
map.manage_user '/users/:id/manage', :controller => :users, :action => :manage
```

and then refer it as

```
link_to 'Manage', manage_user_path(:id => user)
```

**edit**
If that doesn't work, please show your routes.rb file.

Comment: I added a map to get the manage_user and not user section for GET: **map.resources :users, :member => { :manage  => :get }** giving **manage_user GET    /users/:id/manage(.:format)        {:action=>"manage", :controller=>"users"}** but still the same 'manage?id=1' link.  Will try your suggestion.

Comment: WOOPS.  Forgot the second part of your post, the link_to.  It works!  Thanks!!!!  Hmmmm... pretty complicated stuff eheheheh

Comment: **<%= link_to('Edit', manage_user_path(:id => user)) %>** + EITHER( **map.resources :users, :member => { :manage  => :get }** OR **map.manage_user '/users/:id/manage', :controller => :users, :action => :manage** ) = **'/users/1/manage'**.   Thanks again Nikita.

Comment: To clear up: the problem was in the 'link_to' creation, and the 'manage_user' route not being made.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `collection` to `member` in your routes.rb when defining `map.resources :users`. Then you'll get nice `/users/1/manage` link.

Also, when creating a link try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Manage', manage_user_path(user) %>
```

Comment: No, that's for another thing, both with and without :id need work (single --member-- and plural --collection--).  Thanks for the comment though :), yup the link_to needs the path from resource.
map.resources :users, :collection => {:manage => :get} and map.resources :users, :member => { :manage  => :get }